# How do I check a list element inside a dict using jinja2?

Tags: python, templates, django-templates, jinja2

I have a list that looks like below and I wish to access/check the value at an index of the list in the dict in my template using jinja2 :

```
Dict : {'110.34.214.180': [['SR12'], 'Unavailable', '0'], 
        '110.34.214.110': [['SR9'], 'Unavailable', '0'], 
        '105.34.214.184': [['SR11'], 'Available', '0'], 
        '110.34.214.100': [['SR2'], 'Unavailable', '0'], 
        '110.34.214.124': [['SR7'], 'Unavailable', '0'], 
        '110.138.249.238': [['SR5'], 'Unavailable', '0']
       }
```

I wish to check something like this, whether the value[1] is available, then only print value[0] of the list:

```
{% for stations, value in AliasDict.items %}
   {% if value[1] == 'Unavailable' %}
       <a href="#"> {{forloop.counter}}. {{stations}} : {{value[0]}}</a>
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

How do I accomplish this?

```
def render_home_elements(self, request):
    return render(request, 'home/home.html',{'AliasDict':self.teDict})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are pretty close.

Try:

```
import jinja2

AliasDict = {'110.34.214.180': [['SR12'], 'Unavailable', '0'], 
        '110.34.214.110': [['SR9'], 'Unavailable', '0'], 
        '105.34.214.184': [['SR11'], 'Available', '0'], 
        '110.34.214.100': [['SR2'], 'Unavailable', '0'], 
        '110.34.214.124': [['SR7'], 'Unavailable', '0'], 
        '110.138.249.238': [['SR5'], 'Unavailable', '0']
       }

s = """{% for stations, value in AliasDict.items() %}
   {% if value[1] == 'Unavailable' %}
       <a href="#"> {{loop.index}}. {{stations}} : {{value[0]}}</a>
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %} """

template = jinja2.Environment().from_string(s)
data = template.render(AliasDict=AliasDict)
print(data)
```

Comment: Sorry, I want to render the page in the HTML itself. Not in python.

Comment: Use the content from the variable `s` in your html